# General Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes

> Define a generalised Poisson process as an arrival process that begins
>   at time 0 and that satisfies:
>
> - The independence property: the number of arrivals during two non-overlapping intervals are independent.
> - Small interval probabilities:
>
> \begin{align*} P(X_{t+\varepsilon} - X_t \ge 2) &= o(\varepsilon) \\
>  P(X_{t+\varepsilon} - X_t = 1) &= \lambda(t)\varepsilon +
> > o(\varepsilon) \\ P(X_{t+\varepsilon} - X_t = 0) &=
> > 1-\lambda(t)\varepsilon + o(\varepsilon) \end{align*}
>
> The function $\lambda(t)$ is called the intensity function.
>
> Let ${X_t, t \ge 0}$ be a generalised Poisson process (and suppose
>   $\lambda(t)$ is continuous for simplicity). Let $p_n(t) = P(X_t = n)$
>   and $m(t) = \int_0^t \lambda(u) du$

**Question (a)**

Obtain $p_0(t) = P(X_t = 0)$ by showing that $p_0(t)$ solves a first order differential equation.

**My Working**

Define $p_0(t) = P(X_t = 0)$, then for $h > 0$,
\begin{align*}
p_0(t+h) & = P(X_{t+h} = 0) \\
& = P(X_t = 0, X_{t+h} - X_t = 0) \\
& = P(X_t=0)P(X_{t+h} - X_t = 0) \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{By the independence property} \\
& = p_0(t)\left[1-\lambda(t)h + o(h) \right] \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{By the small interval probabilities} \\
& = p_0(t) - p_0(t)\lambda(t)h + p_0(t)o(h)
\end{align*}
By rearranging,
\begin{align*}
\nonumber \frac{p_0(t+h) - p_0(t)}{h} & = -p_0(t)\lambda(t) + p_0(t)\left(\frac{o(h)}{h} \right) \\
\nonumber \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{p_0(t+h) - p_0(t)}{h} \right) & = -p_0(t)\lambda(t) + p_0(t)\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{o(h)}{h} \right) \\
\nonumber p_0'(t) & = -p_0(t)\lambda(t) \\
 p_0'(t) + \lambda(t) p_0(t) & = 0
\end{align*}
where the above is a separable first order linear differential equation.

Solving this differential equation yields,
\begin{align*}
\frac{p_0'(t)}{p_0(t)} &= -\lambda(t) \\
\int \frac{p_0'(t)}{p_0(t)} dt &= -\int \lambda(t) dt \\
\ln\left(|p_0(t)|\right) + C_1 &= -\int_0^t \lambda(u) du + C_2
\end{align*}
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the constants of integration.

Note that since $p_0(t)$ is a probability, then $p_0(t) > 0$ for all $t \ge 0$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\ln\left(p_0(t)\right) = -m(t) + C_3 
\end{align*}
Since $p_0(0) = 1$ and $m(0) = 0$, then $C_3 = 0$, so the solution is given by,
\begin{align*}
p_0(t) = \exp\left(-m(t)\right) \ \ \ \ \forall \ \ 0 \le t < +\infty 
\end{align*}

**Query**

My main query is when removing the absolute values from $\ln\left(|p_0(t)|\right)$ by saying "...since $p_0(t)$ is a probability, then $p_0(t) > 0$ for all $t \ge 0$." How can I actually prove $p_0(t) > 0$ for all $t \ge 0$ based on the properties of a generalised Poisson process?

**Question (b)**

Let $T_1$ be the time of the first arrival. Find the density of $T_1$.

**My working/Query**

Is my working correct here?

From part (a), we know $p_0(t) = \exp\left(-m(t)\right)$. Assume that the process starts from time zero and let $T_1$ denote the time of the first arrival. The CDF of $T_1$ is given by,
\begin{align*}
F_{T_1}(t) = P(T_1 \le t) = 1- P(T_1 > t) = 1-P(X_t = 0) = 1-\exp(-m(t))
\end{align*}
To find the PDF of $T_1$, differentiate the CDF with respect to $t$ yields,
\begin{align*}
f_{T_1}(t) & = m'(t)\exp(-m(t)) \\
& = \lambda(t)\exp(-m(t)) \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus}
\end{align*}
Thus, $f_{T_1}(t) = \lambda(t)\exp(-m(t))$ for all $0 \le t < +\infty$.

Comment: "How can I actually prove p0(t)>0" Because *$p_0(t)$ is a probability* (and not $0$). What is your question, actually?

Comment: Ok, so I guess more precisely, why cant $p_0(t) = P(X_t=0)$ be $0$?

Comment: Because $t\mapsto\mathrm e^{m(t)}p_0(t)$ has derivative zero and $p_0(0)\gt0$.

Comment: What does $t \mapsto e^{m(t)}p_0(t)$ mean? Sorry I'm new to this kind of notation...

Comment: $t\mapsto f(t)$ denotes the function whose value at $t$ is $f(t)$.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense. Also is my derivation of the distribution for the first arrival time correct? Is it very complicated to derive the distribution of the interarrival times of a non homogenous Poisson process?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, $p_0(t)\mathrm e^{m(t)}$ does not depend on $t$ and $p_0(0)=1$ hence $p_0(t)=\mathrm e^{-m(t)}$ for every $t\geqslant0$. Since $p_0(t)=P(T_1\gt t)$, differentiating the function $p_0$, one sees that the density $f_1$ of $T_1$ is such that, for every $t$,
$$
f_1(t)=\lambda(t)\cdot\mathrm e^{-m(t)}\cdot\mathbf 1_{t\gt0}.
$$
More generally, the joint density $f_{1:n}$ of the $n$ first arrivals $T_{1:n}=(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$ is such that, for every $t_{1:n}=(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$,
$$
f_{1:n}(t_{1:n})=\lambda(t_1)\lambda(t_2)\cdots\lambda(t_n)\cdot\mathrm e^{-m(t_n)}\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\lt t_1\lt\cdots\lt t_n}.
$$
The interarrival times are defined as $L_n=T_n-T_{n-1}$ for every $n\geqslant1$, with the convention that $T_0=0$. The change of variable $s_k=t_k-t_{k-1}$ for $k\geqslant1$ with the convention that $t_0=0$ shows that the joint density $g_{1:n}$ of $L_{1:n}=(L_1,\ldots,L_n)$ is such that, for every $s_{1:n}=(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$,
$$
g_{1:n}(s_{1:n})=\lambda(s_1)\lambda(s_1+s_2)\cdots\lambda(s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n)\cdot\mathrm e^{-m(s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n)}\cdot\mathbf 1_{s_1\gt0,s_2\gt0,\ldots,s_n\gt0}.
$$